# Concat two fields into a dropdown menu

Tags: php, sql, concatenation

I am trying to simply display two fields from a table, e.g. firstname, lastname, combine them and display in a dropdown menu that can be selected, and is stored along with other data the user inputs. Below, works for one fields, but i am struggling to combine the lastname, i have tried concat but i think i did that wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
//Drop Down Select
  $sql = "SELECT concat (firstname, lastname) as username  FROM users_tbl";
$result = pg_query($sql);
echo "<select name='firstname'>";

while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
 echo "<option value='" . $row['firstname'] . "'>" . $row['firstname'] ."</option>";

}
echo "</select>";
// close connection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:-

```
$sql = "SELECT concat (firstname, lastname) as username  FROM users_tbl";
$result = pg_query($sql);
echo "<select name='firstname'>";

while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
echo '<option value="'.$row['username'].'" >'.$row['username'].'</option>';
}
echo "</select>";
// close connection
```

Comment: Warning: pg_query() [function.pg-query]: Query failed: ERROR: column "lastname" does not exist at character 27 in /var/www/html/Test/rivers/RiverEnter.php on line 36

Comment: quotations needed? line 36 is the $sql line

Answer (score 1):

Either rely on SQL...

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['username'] . "'</option>";
}
```

OR don't use CONCAT in SQL and do it with PHP:

```
while ($row = pg_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['firstname'] . " " . $row['lastname'] ."'</option>";
}
```

but do not do both.

Comment: my concat statement in my original post is correct? the second option you gave was most like what I have tried from my googling. It didn't work however.

Comment: @Tom: for the 2nd option, change your SQL to `SELECT firstname, lastname, xxx FROM ...`, and see the tiny changes in my PHP example (compared to yours). For the syntax of CONCAT, see the manual of your DB.